# Show model values as multi select options in admin

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to store use the values from two different models to show as choices in form and store them in new model.

Here is what I have now.

models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Product(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=5)

class JobQueue(models.Model):
    emp_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    product_code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
```

forms.py

```
class JobQueueForm(forms.ModelForm):
    emp_choices = Employee._meta.get_field('name').choices
    product_code_choices = Product._meta.get_field('code').choices

    emp_name = forms.ChoiceField(choices = emp_choices)
    product_code =forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=product_code_choices)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        return super(JobQueueForm, self).save(commit = commit)

    class Meta:
        model = JobQueue
        fields = ('emp_name', 'product_code')
```

admin.py

```
class JobQueueAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = JobQueueForm

    fieldsets = (
    (None,{
        'fields': ('emp_name', 'product_code'),}),
)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        super(JobQueueAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
admin.site.register(models.Employee, AuthorAdmin)
admin.site.register(models.Product, ProductAdmin)
admin.site.register(models.JobQueue, JobQueueAdmin)
```

I do have values stored in Employee and Product models, but I dont see them as options in JobQueue model in Admin portal.
Am I missing anything here?

[image]

Comment: You may want to consider using foreign keys and many-to-many fields for the `JobQueue` model, instead of charfields. If, for example you have `emp_name = models.ForeignKey('Employee')` in your model, then you can simply include `emp_name` in `Meta.fields`, and you won't have to set the choices or set `emp_name = forms.ChoiceField(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
emp_choices = Employee._meta.get_field('name').choices
```

This line doesn't make sense. It tries to get the choices for the `Employee.name` field, but you did not specify any choices for the `name` field in your model.

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

If you want generate a list of choices from all the existing employees in the database, then you can define a method that does this:

```
def get_names():
    return Employee.objects.values_list('name', 'name')
```

Then use this method in your form:

```
class JobQueueForm(forms.ModelForm):
    emp_name = forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_names)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks @Alasdair .. This did the trick... I can access the choices now in admin portal.